# Play: Using a configuration property as the value of an annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, playframework

This (obviously) works:

```
@Every("10s")
public class Extinguisher extends Job {
    ...
}
```

...but this doesn't:

```
@Every(Play.configuration.getProperty("my.setting", "10s"))
public class Extinguisher extends Job {
    ...
}
```

When running `auto-test`, the app doesn't start and complains my controllers can't get enhanced because of a `NullPointerException` encountered by javassist.

Is there a way to configure a job scheduling from `application.conf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can schedule your job manually from `@OnApplicationStartup` job:

```
@OnApplicationStartup
public class ExtinguisherBootstrap extends Job { 
    public void doJob() {
        new Extinguisher()
            .every(Play.configuration.getProperty("my.setting", "10s"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether Play or javassist extend what you can do with the Java language, but I can at least point out that the following line is not legal Java:

```
@Every(Play.configuration.getProperty("my.setting", "10s"))
```

For an annotation with a parameter with type *T* and value *V*, the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.7) requires that:

> If *T* is a primitive type or `String`, *V* is a constant expression

In this case, *T*, the type of the annotation parameter, is a `String`, but the value you're trying to set to it isn't a (compile-time) constant expression.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that "configuration" wont be available at that stage.

I don't think what you want to do is possible (as per my current knowledge of Play, maybe someone knows a trick to make it work)

You may be able to "hack it" by having a job run every few seconds and in that job launch the target job as per configuration. It's less efficient, but it may solve your issue

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
@On("cron.noon")
```

Which will look for a line like this in application.conf:

```
cron.noon = 1s
```